# DevEnv Vs2008 crashing on exit when output window is undocked?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

VS2008 SP1

I have a bunch of windows (output, call browser, error list, Find Results 1) docked in the lower pane of VS.

If I simply undock those windows, then go to File->Exit, VS crashes with

"microsoft visual studio has encountered a problem and needs to close"

I attach a debugger, it takes me to line 75 of atlcomcli.h "if (*pp)"

Unhandled exception at 0x40dab6e1 in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.

Answer (score 1):

yea, its a real pain. check out this [KB960075](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960075)